# Отсутствует или не откликается преобразователь pyrcc5 на windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, qrc

Пытаюсь преобразовать изображение в .py, для этого создал файл res_1.grc с кодом -

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/">
   <file>full-img.jpg</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Дальше для завершения процесса мне требуется ввести в консоль вот такую комманду -

```
pyrcc5 res_1.qrc -o kik_rc.py
```

После ввода комманды консоль выдаёт мне 'всеми любимую ошибку' -

```
"pyrcc5" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет мне как это исправить.
P.S: у меня винда.

Comment: ищите где у вас лежит `pyrcc5.exe` и думайте почему у вас нет к нему доступа.

Comment: Я искал, проблема в том, что его просто нет, пролазил все директории питона, да и не только, не подскажете как его установить, если это возможно.